# JavaScript Timeline in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, timeline

I have a JavaScript issue where something doesn't work in Chrome but works in Firefox. Since this is part of a big Web Portal, I cannot easily isolate stuff.

I know that Chrome has a Javascript timeline, but does Firefox have something like that as well? Firebug only seems to set arbitrary breakpoints or "Break on Next", but no way to just see what JavaScript is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Open firebug and click the arrow on the "net" tab. click enable.  Lastly, reload the page.

Comment: That shows me Resources that are loaded, but it doesn't show me which JavaScript functions get executed?

Comment: did you try the "stack" tab under the "Script" tab?

Comment: That only seems to work when I break execution, it's no live graph of anything. I don't know where the error could be, so I'm looking for a live view of any javascript that is executing in the page.

Comment: @MichaelStum then I have no idea :P  The error console is not helping at all?